# Fractional Int error [haskell]

Tags: haskell

```
No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `leap'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
In the first argument of `(==)', namely `leap (x)'
In the second argument of `(&&)', namely `leap (x) == 1'
In the expression: (y == 2) && leap (x) == 1
```

getting this error when loading the file in ghci

this is the func that's causing the error

```
daysInMonth :: Int -> Int -> Int
daysInMonth y x
    | (y == 1 || y == 3 || y == 5 || y == 7 || y == 8 || y == 10 || y == 12) = 31
    | (y == 4 || y == 6 || y == 9 || y == 11) = 30
    | (y == 2) && leap(x) == 1 = 28
    | (y == 2) && leap(x) == 0 = 29
    where
    leap a = if (a / 4) == 0 then return 1 else return 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to calculate `a / 4` where `a` (which only ever equals `x`, an `Int`) is an `Int`.  The `Int` type does not belong to the `Fractional` typeclass, and thus `/` is not defined for `Int`s.  In order to do what you want, you can:

1. Convert `a` to a `Fractional` type by writing `if fromIntegral a / 4 == 0 then ...`
2. Or, if you want to do "integer division" and discard the remainder, write `if quot a 4 == 0 then ...`

Also, `return` in Haskell is not like `return` in other languages.  Get rid of it here.

(Also also, [that's not how you determine leap years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).)

Comment: okay thanks for the advice :) yeh i know our lecturer said use that for the purposes of making it simpler.